# Get name Element By Id or tag in javascript

Tags: html, dom, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, dom-manipulation

Creating the First-time extension for third party sites https://www.viki.com/videos/1151474v to get all or particular element name using get element by ID or tag name and run automatically when the page refreshed or content of the page reloads.

```
var temp =  document.getElementById('html5_player_id_html5');
 alert('Element temp : ' + temp);
```

**Result: Null**

```
var v = document.getElementsByClassName("ad-point");
  alert('Element temp : ' + v[0]); 
  while (v.length >0) v[0];
  alert("Hello timetext");
```

**Result: Undefined**

I start getting a null value when trying to get an element by particular Id or Undefined when clicking the button.

**HTML:**

```
        <button class="btn_click" id="btn_click_id">Click</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var link = document.getElementById('btn_click_id');
  // onClick's logic below:
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
   alert("Button click " + link );

   func();
  });
});   

function func() 
{
 var t = document.getElementById("html5_player_id");
  if(typeof(t) != 'undefined' && t != null)
  {
    alert("T :" + t.length);
    console.log(" Chrome extension go D4d html5 exit");
    timedText();
    alert('Element exists!');          
  } 
   else{
        func();
        alert('Element does not exist!');
       }
}


function timedText() {   setTimeout(myTimeout, 1000) }

function myTimeout()
{ 
  var v = document.getElementsByTagName('id');

  while (v.length >0) v[0];
  alert('Element temp : ' + v[0]); 
  alert("timetext run");
}
```

and console not working if I used console.log so I used

Comment: 1) To access web pages you need to put that code in a content script 2) `while (v.length >0) v[0];` will hang the tab if there's at least one element inside `v`.

Comment: I already try it but it runs one time only after the content page(next video load) it stops working and the same issue appears.

'{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name" : "D4D", "description" : "Extension was created for learning purpose. ",
    "version": "0.0.1", "icons":  {   "128"  : "icon.png" },
    "browser_action" : { "default_icon"   : "icon.png", "default_popup"  : "popup.html"
                           },
    "content_scripts"   : [{ "matches" : ["https://www.viki.com/videos/*"],"js  : [ "content.js"] }],
    "background" : ["activeTab","declarativeContent" ],
}'

Comment: That is an AJAX-driven site, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954).